# ASP.NET Core Web API Controller Object Return Format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

So in ASP.NET Core Web API, it says that objects returned via a controller are wrapped as a POCO (plain old CLR object). And states this:

> Controller actions can return POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects). When a POCO is returned, the runtime automatically creates an ObjectResult that wraps the object. The client gets the formatted serialized object. If the object being returned is null, a 204 No Content response is returned.

Going through the sample app you create in the docs returns a "List" of Objects (Pizza's in this case).

For instance returning a single objects:

```
// GET by Id action
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Pizza> Get(int id)
{
    var pizza = PizzaService.Get(id);

    if (pizza == null)
        return NotFound();

    return pizza;
}
```

It shows up fine, however it says the client formatted it into a serialized object...but doesn't specify the type by default.

It sounds like I can restrict it a controller action to JSON via `[Produces("application/json")]` at the attribute header. But is there a way to specifically restrict it to JSON at a variable level. IE by applying something like `return pizza.toJson()` (I see things for extensions that do this, but I'm talking via default ASP.NET Core methods).

Comment: Do you want to serialize the `pizza` before returning it? Like the `return pizza.toJson()` format in IE? You can directly return a `new JsonResult(pizza)` like this: `public async Task<ActionResult<Pizza>> Get(int id){ return new JsonResult(pizza) }`.

Comment: Yeah basically, the MS Docs didn't really specify HOW to do that exactly (except with an external library)

Comment: Hi @msmith1114, Microsoft official does not seem to provide sample code specifically for this item, but it mentions using `JsonResult` to return data in JSON format, please check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#format-specific-action-results-2). You can also check [JsonResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to view more details.